# Add a custom file type with java application installation

Tags: java, c#, c++

I am trying to have my custom file type `.vrs` (which for all intents and purposes is an rich text format).
I am pleased with what I have since I am self taught.
But am having difficulties associating that file with my program so that when a user double clicks it, it automatically open my document editor.

All searches so far have come up with either right clicking and setting the association, but this is not what I would need.

> I may not have explained as well as needed so think Photoshop's `.psd` when you install Photoshop all `psd` files are automatically set to open when you double click them.

Hopefully I have been clear enough for you to help.

Also whilst the question is regarding Java any resource be it for C# C++ etc, would also be appreciated.

Thanks for your time and any responses.

Comment: Does your editor open the filename given as first argument?

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c

Comment: Create your file with `.vrs` and register it in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is system dependent, and in Windows involves the registry. If you really want to delve into this, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245262/c-program-needs-an-file-association) post, which goes into great detail on how to accomplish programmatically setting a file extension association using C++. If this is helpful, please write back telling us how you solved the problem in your individual situation.

If that isn't helpful I would try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c) instead, as it links to more resources and demonstrates a little C# code.