# C++ How to make a file type "openable" like a zip file in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

In windows explorer, you can open a zip file as if it was a folder. I want to be able to convince Windows Explorer to browse my new file type so people can view (and possibly open) my 'sub-files' within my file type

what is required to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20256714/1870760

Comment: It's called a [Shell Namespace Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx). Not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: @JameyD that's not nearly enough.

Comment: _"what is required to do this?"_ Research.

Answer (score 1):

As @jonathan-potter mentioned, you'd need a Windows Shell Extension to do this seamlessly. There's a workaround, though. If you, for instance, have the file extension *.dmj* that you want to browse in Explorer, you can create a [File Association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144156(v=vs.85).aspx) between *.dmj* files and your application. Then, when a *.dmj* file is opened in your application, you can create a temporary folder with the corresponding files and structure, and then [open that folder in Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232(v=vs.85).aspx). This is relatively trivial to implement and should give the illusion of the file being browsable with Windows Explorer.

Comment: The tricky bit is figuring out when it's safe to delete the temporary folder.

Comment: This is true. Personally, I'd use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemHandleInformation` to get all of the handles held by Explorer. Then, I'd pipe each result into `NtDuplicateObject` to get a duplicate handle and use `NtQueryObject` with `ObjectNameInformation` to see which file the handle points to. Rinse and repeat this until none of the handles point to my temporary folder or anything inside of it.

Comment: I figured it would have to use the Shell Extension, but I could not see a way of assocating the behaviour to a file type.

Comment: also - the problem with using a temp directory is that it can't show up in the directory tree in explorer (as far as I can tell)